# Will manually upgrade my Nexus 5 to Android 5 wipe my data?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, cyanogenmod

I haven't recieved the OTA yet for lollipop and I would like to manually install it. However, I've read that in order to do this, an unlock to the bootloader has to be done and therefore all my data will be erased. BUT, recently i've already done this unlocking action because I've installed Cyanogenmod, so bootloader is already unlocked.

My question is, in that case, if doing this upgrade will still erase all my data, or I'll manage to keep it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question belongs on [Android Enthusiast](https://android.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Nevertheless, flashing a new ROM over a current one should not wipe your device and your data should be fine. In fact, I did it myself a couple of hours ago (5.0 to 5.0.1). However, you should note that this practice is usually frowned upon by most, especially when transitioning between ROMs of different configuration (in your case Cyanogen to Stock).

So to answer your question: no. Flashing an image to you Nexus 5 will not wipe your data but you **should** do a clean wipe before flashing a new image (of a different config).

*p.s., Do a [NAND backup](https://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fgoogle-nexus-5%2Fhelp%2Fnandroid-backup-t2548658&ei=-LubVPPrLceNuATrnoDoCQ&usg=AFQjCNH7N4AqNK664oCPSyhAFtY_o61KhA&sig2=zH38TdzxSrrCTGMicZU5QA&bvm=bv.82001339,d.c2E) and restore it after you done flashing instead. It's the proper way to do it.*

Comment: Can you please guide me through backing up my device?

Comment: ok I've done that. Now do you have a link to a friendly guide to manually uprgrade to lollipop? (last question, I think)

Comment: This should guide you: http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/tutorial-how-to-flash-factory-image-t2513701

Comment: Just updating that the upgrade process has completed smoothly and successfully. Now recovering everything. Thanks again